# Question regarding calculus origins

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Basically, I'm struggling with Calculus a lot. It's not the concepts that my university is teaching me anymore. I believe it's my brain asking 'why?' every time I do a problem. I've been struggling with the same problem since I was introduced to trigonometry and calculus years ago. So here are three questions that seem to be consistently ruining me:

Why do we make use of the sinusoidal wave? Like, why does $\sin(x)$ start at $ 0$ and then repeat itself when $x = 2\pi$? Likewise for cosine and its own properties.

Furthermore, why were they also turned into hyperbolic functions? Like $\cosh^{-1}(x)$ and whatnot.

Derivation. It's easy. However, I still turn my head and think, why did someone decide to multiply functions by their coefficient power and then reduce their power by 1? Just went over phase plots and it's clear what the use of derivation and integration is. It's just, why? I did ask a university professor this exact question and he told me it's just a stroke of genius from someone in the past. Is this really how it always goes? A genius will come up with things like this and it'll just get fed to everyone without question?

Moreover, why do universities still make us do this stuff by hand? I'd shove it all into wolframalpha if I had to do any of these problems for real.

I guess I just really hate being told something without reasoning...

Comment: Do you know the definition of derivative? As in the limit as $h\to 0$ of some fraction?

Comment: some of what you are asking is just definition. The Sine function is useful. You can define any function you'd like but only SOME of the functions are going to be of use for, say, Engineering.

Comment: Your questions have trivial and very easy answers. I just go to your two last paragraphs. You said "You don't like things without reasons", good! So now, look at things you say for a question with families of parameters, if I claim its validity and show you only several specific examples I calculated with a software then it is cheating! It is just a conjecture. For real prove I have to bring a logical reason and describe what is happening that the formula is valid, for finding the story one needs to go by hands and experience the story himself.

Comment: @5xum yes I do. I was just in such a hurry to post this question because I couldn't stand another second of this madness. Thanks for clarifying though.

Comment: @amcalde but why does sine behave the way it behaves? Like, why was this infinite wave discovered and called 'sine'?

Comment: But if you know what the definition of derivation, then you know that it's not just "multiply this function by its coefficient power and reduce its power by $1$". This rule is just a **consequence** of the definition.

Comment: @5xum was it a mathematical genius who was doing some calculation of the orbit of a planet who wrote down lim h -> 0 or lim h -> inf? They tell us these concepts and I understand them just fine. I just really don't know why there is no explanation as to why we do these problems the way we do them which is why I'm trying to really dig into the origins and reasoning.

Comment: Well the derivative is more or less naturally defined. There is not much genious there. The genious part was when Newton and Leibnitz (independently) discovered that antiderivatives are directly connected to the area under the curve of a functin.

Comment: @5xum and since then it has just been told to us that to find the area under a standard curve you definitely integrate from a to b. That's why I asked such a question. Thanks for your response :)

Comment: It behaves that way because it is designed (defined) to. That is really all there is to it. There are other functions that start off looking like Sine but die down and do not 'wave on' forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things change. Having observed this for millenia, people have wondered:how, and why do they change? In particular, calculus grew out of a desire to understand the laws governing moving bodies.

For moving bodies, the motion itself seems to depend on other things: an attempt to describe this dependence was one of the reasons we study FUNCTIONS. For example, the distance a moving object travels often depends on how much time has elapsed, so we might write: $D = f(t)$.

We measure success in understanding by its predictave power. A curious fact emerged-the ability to predict long-term behavior accurately depended on being able to measure short-term behavior accurately. Put another way: some things not only change, they change "fluidly" or "continually". Velocity might change moment-to-moment.

But how do you measure "instantaneous change" when it involves a ratio whose denominator is $0$? This proved to be a very difficult question, and it's answer led to far-reaching developments.

The answer being, of course, "limits", which although appearing to be a NUMERICAL concept, was actually SPATIAL. Even though mankind had been using "magnitudes" for "measurement" for centuries (or more), we had a lot of trouble understanding what might, or might not, BE a "magnitude".

Our first idea was to measure "by comparison". This idea (ratios, or "commensuration") was adequate for many purposes, but it's inability to rectify solutions of polynomial equations had been known since antiquity.

So if we want to measure things, we need a system of "numbers" that has ALL limits of things we KNOW are numbers (fractions). Something "denser" than rational numbers, that has the "liquid" quality of being able to faithfully encapsulate any rational approximation.

Even the founding fathers of calculus did not fully comprehend the need for such a framework, which we now call the "real numbers". They spoke in vague terms of "vanishing infinitesimals" which was objectionable to many philosophers and scientists.

To fully understand laws of motion (and other dependence relationships), especially over long periods of time (think astronomy) one needs to understand what is happening "instantaneously". Things change, and it's happening right NOW.

It appears to be an "impossible" problem to solve, and when people were first exposed to the "infinitesimal calculus" (calculating with these "very small quantities") they did not believe it was logically sound. We did not even have the proper TOOLS (real numbers) to capture the reasons we felt justified "why it worked". Epsilons and deltas, and Cauchy sequences, lagged quite some time behind a bewildering display of "integrals" and "derivatives" that seemed to prove something useful, but on shaky premises. But their predictive power could not be denied, and when we find something useful, we generally are very motivated to understand WHY it's useful.

There's MUCH more to be said about this-people are quite inventive critters, and if a concept doesn't exist yet to describe what we see, we're apt to INVENT one. The functions you study now were all given names and form by "someone" (or groups of "someones") over quite some time. The history of a single function (like sine, for example) is much too involved to address in a setting like this-it would take a BOOK.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here are some attempts. There are probably better explanations, but I'll give it a shot.

The trigonometric functions are often times referred to as circular functions, this is because they can be defined using a circle. That is, $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ return $y$ and $x$ components respectively of a radially arm around a unit circle. Since there are $2 \pi$ radians in a circle, these functions repeat on on intervals $[k \pi, (k+2)\pi)$ as the radial arm has completed a cycle.

As for the history of trig functions, I can't speak to that. But they're properties have been very useful for a variety of mathematical fields. They crop up in differential equations, fourier analysis, complex analysis, etc. Someone with more breadth and depth can probably answer this part far better, but it appears orthogonality is a big reason why $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ have many uses.

Likewise, hyperbolic functions hold many uses in common problems in mathematics. They hold many similar properties of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ and this is not for arbitrary reasons. You may have seen Euler's formula $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$. Well, by definition

$$  \cosh(x) = \frac{e^x +e^{-x}}{2} $$ ,
then 
$$ \cosh(ix) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} = \frac{\cos(x) + i\sin(x) + \cos(-x) +i\sin(-x)}{2} = \frac{2\cos(x)}{2} = \cos(x) $$

Once again, their use crops up in a lot of mathematical problems which extend into physics/engineering.

Finally, the power rule is a provable fact simply from the definition of the derivative and binomial expansion. Whether it was discovered by a stroke of genius or hard work and ingenuity, I do not know. I'd imagine it was a bit of both, genius for the intuition, hard work for the proof. Proofs are important because things like wolfram alpha could not do what it does without a solid understanding and explanation of the content matter. Computation gives insight into a problem or fully describe on singular question. Proofs extract generalities of classes of problems.

I have to go now, sorry if this was brief. Take it with a grain of salt. I look forward to other answers.

Comment: Thank you for your clarity. It definitely did help!

Answer (score 0):

You ask a couple of questions.

1) You say that you are having a hard time getting your head wrapped around some of these concepts you are learning because you are thinking: why would anyone do this? Where did this come from? How did people come up with this? What is the use of this?

I actually think it is good that you are thinking about these things, and a good teacher should (IMO) motivate the topics by explaining (briefly) where (1) this comes from, and (2) what the use of the topic is. It can, however, be hard to fit this into a calculus class because of lack of time. Many other students don't care and prefer that the teacher use the time on doing examples that are similar to what might be on an exam.

Now, even though it is good that you are asking these questions, mathematics is also the art of abstraction. You want to be able to approach a concept without worrying too much about the uses and the motivation. In my experience one often understands these things later on. So, for now I would advice you to worry less about these questions. Try to approach your class and the material taught as an abstract game. Pay attention to how everything fits together on an abstract level. Focus on learning the techniques involved in solving the problems and try to enjoy this process. Many mathematicians enjoy mathematics for this reason. They like the preciseness and the algorithms that are involved in solving a problem. They also like the game of trying to find the correct tools to apply. Why does this tool work and not the other?

Now, to find the tool that works, you often have to understand a bit about what is going on. If you are trying to determine ho fast something is changing, then you know that this is how derivatives are defined. If you are trying to find the largest value of something you know (or will know) that this is the process of optimization where derivatives again are involved. You need to level of understanding of the concepts, but I think you are over-thinking it.

Then, so try and ask your teacher in his/her office hours about some of the motivation behind what you are learning. But, remember that there is a rich and large history behind these concepts. It would take you quite some time to fully grasp where this is coming from. And the purpose of calculus isn't to teach this (primarily) it is to teach to to *do* the derivatives.

2) You also ask about why universities are emphasizing doing it by hand when it can be done with a computer program. A computer program / calculator can do some cool stuff, but it can't translate a word problem into equations. Try to put into Wolfram the problem: If I If I have two apples and take away one how many to do I have? If a train is going at 200 mph and is experiencing an deceleration of 10 miles per hour^2, when does the train stop? You need to do the thinking in this problem. And you need to know about derivatives to solve the problem. Then, yes, you can use your calculator to actually solve the question. But you need to understand the concepts first and the best (or one) way to do this is getting your hands dirty.

Also, calculus (mathematics) isn't just about learning mechanical computations, but also about learning to think (abstractly). You have a problem with strange symbols asking you to find something. How are you going to do this? What is a good approach. How can I try different things and evaluate the success of my attempts? This is all stuff you learn to do behind the scenes.